# Enter Float in the database (more numbers are entered) C# Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and C# to insert some rows into this database. The first column of this table is a code (type `varchar(20)`) and the second one is a `float`. The problem arises because if I want to enter 3,71, the database stores 3,7100000381469727.

Code:

```
float superficieL = float.Parse(row.Cells[indexSuperficie].Value.ToString(), new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

The value inserted in the database as a float is this variable, and I get his value from a datagridview that only contains 3,71.

More examples:

- (DB)001122 - 0,9100000262260437
- (DB)335T1613 -   0,5
- (DB)335T1642 - 3,869999885559082
- (DB)335T1644 - 3,7100000381469727

Why is this happening?

Comment: what is data type in SQL table ?  Are you able to retrieve it properly ?  And I believe it is 3,71 after parsing and not 3,51 as you mentioned in question ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari sorry Manoj, I've edited the post.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: This is inherit to floating point. More information: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. If you want to store numbers more accurately you can switch to using decimal datatype in MSSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please [refer this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) for understanding how float, double and decimal data type works in .NET

Also, please [refer this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types?view=sql-server-ver15) which suggests what are options available to store decimals in a SQL Server database.

You can either use real, float or decimal type for your case.

In your case, I would suggest to use the `Decimal` datatype in a SQL Server table, as it provides better precision and I believe that's what you asked for.

Hope this helps.